# Tracking email opens in Outlook using Google Analytics

Tags: vb.net, google-analytics, outlook

I am trying to track the number of people that open newsletter using Google Analytics.

I am using the following code to do so:

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&cid=1&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=NewsletterTest1&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=NewsletterTest1"/>
```

It kind of works... I am sending it to a lot of people (around 300) and they all only count as 1 because of the CID.

I was trying to avoid making a VB to send it, I don't want to over complicate it.

Is there any workaround? I can't use any other tool as I am inside a corporate environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Different CID for each user

You have to use unique **CID** for every user. Generate it in your database or collect it on website and save it in your database and then use it in emails. **This is a must!**

### 2. Use CNAME record for anayltics tracker

Data are normally collected by **google-analytics.com/collect** but is very useful when you make your custom subdomain, like **tracker.mydomain.com/collect** and there is a **CNAME** record aiming to **google-analytics.com/collect**

### 3. Make you custom script for enhancing signals

Use your custom script on subdomain, e.g. **collector.mydomain.com** where you capture meta-signals like c**ollector.mydomain.com/collect?campaign=SummerSale2015&cid=654FG79E3A54D** and you translate (enahnce with property ID, page name, content groups, custom diemnsions, etc...) then into MeasurementProtocol and send them by cURL for instance.

> PS: Do not use method described at the google analytics developers for
>   email tracking. It is not a reliable way. I tested id in various
>   scenarios and methods described above are the best we found.